# WebStorm and Jade output setting

Tags: pug, webstorm

I'm trying to setup a watcher for compiling Jade files. But I can't setup the "public" folder as output folder. This is my situation.

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the command line option `--out public` as an argument.
Here's a setup that would put the compiled files to the `public` folder.
You can read more about Jade command line options here: http://jade-lang.com/command-line/

Edit: Working directory should be $ProjectFileDir$

[image]

Comment: it won't work... it creates a folder named "public" (with the .html file compiled into it) into "jade" folder... "public" and "jade" folders are at the same level.

Comment: Please try to set Working directory to $ProjectFileDir$